# Class segmentation fault (11)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Please follow the steps below:

1. Create New `Firemonkey Moblie Application`
2. Add `TGeustureManager` component to the Form
3. Add 2 `TButton` components to the Form

   - Button1.Text: "Button1: Do something..."
   - Button2.Text: "Button2: Exit Application..."

   [image: The application should appear like this]
4. Double click on Button2 Component and write the following code for `OnClick` Event:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if MessageDlg('Are you sure you want to Exit?', TMsgDlgType.mtWarning,
             [TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0) = mrYes then
       SharedActivity.finish;
   end;
   ```
5. Run the application in debug mode.
6. on the device, click the button 2, then click yes to the popped up message. An exception will appear:

   [image]

Why is this exception raised?

I thought it is related to unused `TGeustureManager` component. but NO it is **NOT**:

1. If you open the `Location` Demo project that comes with Delphi xe5.
2. Add `TButton` component to `Location` Label as shown in the image below:
   [image]
3. Add the same code as above to `OnClick` Event.
4. Run the application, and click on Button5, you will get the same exception.

Is this a bug should I report? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have precisely the same exception all over the place, not related to terminating my app. Sad I cannot find much info about it. Only happens on anything in Firemonkey which is NOT Windows. Windows works fine, all others fail. Some of it I figured out (for example I needed to use generics `TList<>` rather than the old `TList`) but now the `XSuperObject` library does this when parsing a file (which is a correctly formatted JSON file in the correct location).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly that you are killing the activity that is running, before its execution flow has been exhausted, thereby causing problems. Much like freeing a form in a form method....

What happens if you replace:

`SharedActivity.finish`

with:

```
uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android;
...
CallOnUIThread(procedure begin SharedActivity.finish end);
```

[ Typed from memory, so may need some tweaking ]

Comment: Thanks Blong for your reply.

I found no documentation about CallOnUIThread. and the code you posted does not work.

Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: When you say "does not work" do you mean does not compile, or does not improve the runtime situation? CallOnUIThread you can check the syntax of in the unit whose name is cited. Yes, it's not documented. Except in the source. Which I assume you have.

Comment: But thinking about it now, maybe running the same call on a different thread won't improve matters. You need to defer the call, as Release does in VCL land. I'll think on it more.

Comment: I mean, it gives me syntax error.
I really appreciate your occupation on this matter @blong!

Comment: I think CallOnUIThread is in Androidapi.Helpers (either there or in FMX.Helpers.Android).
You can easily find out by searching through the RTL Android source files.
You can do this in the IDE's Find in Files option (Ctrl+Shift+F), searching in $(BDS)\source\rtl\android or $(BDS)\source\fmx or you can pull down the excellent free search tool Agent Ransack and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted Embarcadero for this issue.

They said that it is because TApplication.Terminate is not yet implemented in FireMonkey platform for mobile.

They open a ticket to implement TApplication.Terminate in nex hot fix.

Let's hope that will not take ages.

Comment: Which Issue number on Quality Central?

Answer (score 0):

if you want only to close application un can try this:

```
case MessageDlg('Close Application?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
    [
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes,
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo
    ], 0) of
    { Detect which button was pushed and show a different message }
    mrNo:
      showmessage('');
    mrYes:
      halt;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks @user193149, I am seeking to find out why is this exception is raised. Anyway, doing your way, raises the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error on a very simple Location test app, it happens when setting text on a label.  The label was set to auto size, and when I changed it to a static size the error went away.

Delphi XE6, line 681 in FMX.TextLayout.GPU

I am using a Samsung S4 phone.

```
procedure TForm_StayTogether.LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Sender: TObject;
  const OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
begin
  DistLabel.Text:= FloatToStr(LocationSensor1.Distance);
  AccLabel.Text:= FloatToStr(LocationSensor1.Accuracy);
  LatLabel.Text:= FloatToStr(NewLocation.Latitude);
  LonLabel.Text:= FloatToStr(NewLocation.Longitude);
end;
```

Answer (score -4):

I've just experienced something similar, a very tiny app with little code giving this same error (Segmentation fault 11) every single time I quit the app on the Android device (Galaxy Note 2 in my case).

For what it's worth, the problem disappeared when I went to the Stylebook I had earlier put on the form and cleared it. I think I had earlier copied that Stylebook from another test unit.

Mike