# First chance exception - Segmentation fault (11) on run on 2.3 - XE5 Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Does anyone know what's going on with this segmentation fault (11) in XE5 when run on android 2.3 emulator?

I saw two other posts here on SO:
[Class segmentation fault (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875029/class-segmentation-fault-11)
[Android delphi application Segmentation fault (11) exception when calling Firedac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839990/android-delphi-application-segmentation-fault-11-exception-when-calling-fireda)

But none of these aren't my problem. I can't seem to run even an empty project, as I get this error when ran in debug mode, and the app just closes on Android itself.

I found that there was an issue fixed, stated as:

> 117153  Default FMX app crashes on Android 2.3.3 without permission [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43359)

So I went to an empty project and set all permissions to True, but it still crashes.

I just got XE5 Update 1. But from the link above, I can't find the info in which version of XE5 was the bug fixed, and why there's nowhere stated as normal bug, but rather as "without permission".

Haven't really tried on the real device below 2.3.7 (on which the app works just fine), as I don't have any, but in emulator only, which is 2.3, and can't be selected to other than this, however I do need to run the app on 2.3.5 phone (I'm actually doing an app specifically for Samsung Galaxy S plus).

**Is there any info if this error also occurs in 2.3.5 or is this just 2.3.3 issue, or just emulator issue...?**

As [@David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) stated in the post above, it's some memory accessing issue, but I can't seem to find out why and what is the app trying to access, if it's empty?

The code I'm trying to run is literally empty:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) clearly states that the Gingerbread (2.3.3-2.3.7) emulator is not supported. See the two lines marked with ** below.

The solution is to develop directly on the device  instead of the emulator. (You'll find this works much better in actuality anyway; the Android emulators on Windows are pretty slow.)

> RAD Studio supports development on ARMv7 devices that run the following versions of the Android operating system:

```
Android OS Name  Android OS Versions  API Levels  
KitKat 
 Android 4.4 
 API Level 19 

Jelly Bean 
 Android 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 4.3.x 
 API Levels 16, 17, 18 

Ice Cream Sandwich 
 Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 
 API Level 15 

Gingerbread 
 **Android 2.3.3 – 2.3.7**
 API Level 10 


Notes: RAD Studio does not support the following: 
Honeycomb (Android 3.x) 
**Gingerbread emulator** 
Tegra 2 devices (NEON support is required)
```

Comment: Piuuuu... After all of these info that I've been looking at, and focused on the fact that most of the 2.3 devices do have ARMv7 proc, I totally missed that part of the info :// Knew about honeycomb, but didn't put a focus on the gingerbread emulator :/
Thank you for this one.
Yes, I know that running on devices is far more time efficient, but right now I only have 4.3, 4.0 and 2.2 (which doesn't have ARMv7, so can't run them) devices available, so emulator was my only choice.
I guess I'll rather get my friend busy with testing on his 2.3.7 ;)